# Accessing getProperty() outside of class

Tags: java

```
public static Properties defaultProps = new Properties();
      static {
        try {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
            defaultProps.load(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      public static String getProperty(String database) {
        return defaultProps.getProperty(database);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println(...key database?);
        // this is the part where I try to test if I can print the property 'database'
        // I also try to make it available to other classes, tried using public statics,
        }
```

This is my code in which I retrieve the properties from properties file `config.properties`. However, I want to be able to print property N (here: `database`) and be able to use property N in other classes.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: And what's the problem? Note that in `getProperty(String database)` `database` is the name of the key parameter, not the value. You probably want to call it like `YourClass.getProperty("database")` but calls like ``YourClass.getProperty("some other totally independent property")` would work as well - again: `String database` means the _parameter_ is _named_ `database`, not that the _value_ is `"database"`.

Comment: Doing any kind of IO (including reading a file) inside a static initializer is pretty evil.  That said, what exactly is your problem?  The Properties variable is public, just read it.

Comment: Brainfart. Sorry, thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so just call

```
System.out.println(getProperty("database"));
```